# Javascript window function load

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

i have this problem, I would like to load a text inside a div with .innerHTML but after the event click the text inside the div diseappers:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Anagrafica</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Document</h1>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">

    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){      
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function({
      document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML= 'hello';
});
```

Comment: Please give us more information , you can use code snippet for online demo. Than you will get fast answer.

Comment: ok, when i click on button, load the page and document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML= 'hello'; is not print

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: A submit button ... submits your page to the server, causing it (in this case) to reload. It does this while your code for adding your text runs, so you never see it. Use `type="button"` or `return false` from the submit button's event handler. BTW, you are getting errors in your console if that is truly your code...

Comment: yes, i add code snippet

Comment: As @MikeMcCaughan pointed, **Change type="submit" to type="button"**, it should work.

Comment: Please accept best answer , no thank you great or nice ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error , )} missing .

> addEventListener('click', function({

Looks like callback but you need just function(){} to attach.

```js
 window.addEventListener('load',function(){      


   document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
   
     document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML= 'hello';
     
   }, false);


 }, false);
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color:black;color:lime;width:300px" > ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On html

```
<button type='submit'></button>
```

On js

```
var Button = document.querySelector("button");

Button.addEventListener("click", onClickButton, false);
 function onClickButton(){

    // to do something here

  }
```